# Will a Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 be compatible with my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: lens, nikon, compatibility, vivitar

I have a Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 close focusing auto zoom. I'm not a photographer and I would like to know if it can work with a Nikon D3100. On the ring (bottom) it's written "patents applied for N/Ai Lens made in Japan".

Comment: Thank you but I've just received an answer, then it's ok, and more, I tryed to put the photo here (on the question page) and that didn't work, I don't know why 'cause I use "jpeg" from my own pc... so .....but I've my answer then thank you very much, kind regards, Marie-Jo

Answer (score 3):

The N/Ai indicates that it's a Nikon AI mount lens. [This does fit your D3100](https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3100/compatibility02.htm). There are some caveats listed on the Nikon compatibility chart linked.

But, to summarize, yes - it should mount and work (as well as an old manual lens can be expected to work).

Comment: Doing some test shots in "difficult" situations (eg against the light) to learn what the lens can and cannot handle is advisable before doing any critical work with old zooms...

Comment: @rackandboneman agreed. I was tempted to add into my answer the advice of scrapping the lens, as OP stated they're not a photographer...and it's generally only gear obsessed photographers that even bother mounting manual lenses to digital bodies (those aware of the needs of those lenses and potential issues). But, alas...decided to leave out the advice.

Comment: Wonder if the intended meaning was "not a professional photographer" or "not a photography enthusiast" - in the second case I would have said "give the lens to one who is" :)